# How to search in column that was added using addColumn?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I have a few columns where I need to combine data of some columns into one and style them and add some text.

This is an added row for example:

```
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->addColumn('status', function ($data) {                       
                       if ($data->status== '0') return "Not confirmed";
                       else return "Confirmed";

        // ...
  

    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [           
            Column::computed('status')
            // ...
```

How to search in that row by the text? ("Confirmed" or "Not confirmed")?

Comment: do you use serverSide ?